# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2014'

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I'm getting this error UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2014'

I'm trying to load lots of news articles into a MySQLdb. However I'm having difficulty handling non-standard characters, I get hundreds of these errors for all sorts of characters. I can handle them individually using .replace() although I would like a more complete solution to handle them correctly.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-21:~/scripts/work$ python test_db_load_error.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_db_load_error.py", line 27, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql_load)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 157, in execute
    query = query.encode(charset)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 158: ordinal not in range(256)
```

My script;

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
from goose import Goose
import string
import datetime

host = 'rds.amazonaws.com'
user = 'news'
password = 'xxxxxxx'
db_name = 'news_reader'
conn = mdb.connect(host, user, password, db_name)

url = 'http://www.dailymail.co.uk/wires/ap/article-3060183/Andrew-Lesnie-Lord-Rings-cinematographer-dies.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490'
g = Goose()
article = g.extract(url=url)
body = article.cleaned_text
body = body.replace("'","`")
load_date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
summary = article.meta_description
title = article.title
image = article.top_image

sql_load = "insert into articles " \
        "    (title,summary,article,,image,source,load_date) " \
        "     values ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');" % \
        (title,summary,body,image,url,load_date)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_load)
#conn.commit()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is reconfiguring your database to store UTF-8 instead of Latin-1 an option? It'd require a re-code of existing data (a data migration).

Comment: What kind of database char codification do you have? Have you defined it or is it the mysql default? If it is that you have latin1 but maybe you need utf-8 depending on what you want to insert

Comment: You really should be using *SQL parameters* here, not use string interpolation. Remove the `% (....)` from the `sql_load` line and move the tuple to the second argument of `cursor.execute()`. `sql_load = ".... query string with %s placeholders ..."` and `cursor.execute(sql_load, (title, summary, body, image, url, load_date))`.

Comment: thanks, you're all correct. My application is still in testing so I just dropped all the tables and re-created them using charset=utf8. Now everything works. :)

Comment: I'm suddenly getting this same error when I try to insert. How can I find out if this comes from the MySQL server, or from SQLAlchemy (which by default should use utf-8, especially with Py3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database is actually configured for Latin-1, then you cannot store non-Latin-1 characters in it. That includes [U+2014, EM DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm).

The ideal solution is to just switch to a database configured for UTF-8. Just pass `charset='utf-8'` when initially creating the database, and every time you connect to it. (If you already have existing data, you probably want to use MySQL tools to migrate the old database to a new one, instead of Python code, but the basic idea is the same.)

However, sometimes that isn't possible. Maybe you have other software that can't be updated, requires Latin-1, and needs to share the same database. Or maybe you've mixed Latin-1 text and binary data in ways that can't be programmatically unmixed, or your database is just too huge to migrate, or whatever. In that case, you have two choices:

- Destructively convert your strings to Latin-1 before storing and searching. For example, you might want to convert an em dash to `-`, or to `--`, or maybe it's not all that important and you can just convert all non-Latin-1 characters to `?` (which is faster and simpler).
- Come up with an encoding scheme to smuggle non-Latin-1 characters into the database. This means some searches become more complicated, or just can't be done directly in the database.

Comment: How do I find out how the database is configured one way or the other?

Answer (score 7):

When you create your mysqldb connection pass the `charset='utf8'` to the connection.

```
conn = mdb.connect(host, user, password, db_name, charset='utf8')
```

Comment: Provided there isn't any pre-existing data, that is. Otherwise you need to re-code that data in a migration.

Comment: It seems that [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.encoding) sets utf-8 by default. However, how can I make sure it's set to utf-8, or how can I query an existing configuration for it?